# Traffic become lighter or loosen up?

Tags: phrase-request, american-english, phrase-choice

What's the most natural way to say(USA) we want to wait for the traffic become lighter? I can think of following but neither sounds good to my ear.

1. Wait till traffic becomes lighter.
2. Wait till traffic loosen up.
3. Wait till traffic goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We certainly use the adjectives "heavy" and "light" with traffic. So

> Wait till the traffic becomes lighter

is a good sentence, you could also use "gets lighter" in spoken English.

Speaking of the traffic being "tight" or "loose" suggests that the cars cannot move at all.  That may be the case in some cities. I'd understand what you mean here.

I'd also understand "goes away" but that sounds rather odd.

There are lots of other ways to communicate the same idea

> Wait until rush hour is over.
>   Wait till the roads are less busy.
>   Wait an hour so that the traffic will be quieter.